# ng-src not showing image - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to ng-repeat a set of image paths but the images are not loading. Tried both ng-src and src, none works.

HTML file:

```
<div ng-app="homeIndexApp">
    <div ng-controller="homeIndexController">
        <div ng-repeat="x in pics">
             <img ng-src="{{x.source}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js file:

```
var homeIndex = angular.module('homeIndexApp', []);

homeIndex.controller('homeIndexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pics = [{ source: 'images/slides/Slide4.png' },
        { source: 'images/slides/Slide5.png' },
        { source: 'images/slides/Slide1.png' },
        { source: 'images/slides/Slide2.png' },
        { source: 'images/slides/Slide3.png' }
    ];
});
```

However, when I inspect element in my browser, I can hover over the src tag and see the image thumbnail:

```
<img ng-src="images/slides/Slide4.png" src="images/slides/Slide4.png">
```

#### Folder Setup: ASP.NET Core MVC

[image: Folder Setup: ASP.NET Core MVC]

Why don't they show up in the website? What is wrong with the codes?

Comment: what is your image path

Comment: images/slides/Slide4.png

Comment: it should work, anyother console errors?

Comment: Nope, Tried with different browsers too, still not working

Comment: Can you show your project folder setup?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoanH.jpg @Vivz

Comment: Your above js is in which folder?

Comment: Is the app running? Did the controller initialize?

Comment: Yes the app is running, only the pics not showing up... the js found in wwwroot>js

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in this example:

```js
var homeIndex = angular.module('homeIndexApp', []);

homeIndex.controller('homeIndexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pics = [
        { source: '//i.imgur.com/vM1snTA.jpg' },
        { source: '//i.imgur.com/OB2vpNi.jpg' },
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="homeIndexApp">
    <div ng-controller="homeIndexController">
        <div ng-repeat="x in pics">
             <img ng-src="{{x.source}}" height=100>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am actually using MVC in ASP.NET Core. The 'ng-app' is found in the _Layout.cshtml. Does this make a difference?